# How to switch axes in SymPy?

Tags: python, plot, jupyter-notebook, sympy

**Overview of Problem**

I am trying to graph a position v. time graph on Jupyter Notebooks using SymPy and I want to switch the x-axis with the y-axis and vice versa.

**Code**

```
import sympy as sym

t = sym.Symbol('t')

f = 6*t**3+5*t**2-3*t+16

sym.plot(f, (t,0,100), title = '1-D motion through time', xlabel = 'Time', ylabel = 'Space (m)', line_color = 'red' )
```

**This is the graph when I run the code in Jupyter:**

[image]

**I want to alter the code so it looks like this:**

[image]

I am using SymPy because I find it the easiest for a beginner (me) to do derivatives and graph them. I found the second image using matplotlib but can't find an easy way to do derivatives in matplotlib that I understood.

***                        EDIT!!!***

So after putting these back into my code, I just compiled all the things I've found in case anyone else has the same question as me!

**This is the graph using just MatPlotLib**

```
t = np.linspace(0,100,200)
x = 6*t**3+5*t**2-3*t+16

plt.plot(x / 1e6,t, 'b-')
plt.title('1-D motion through time')
plt.xlabel('Space (m) (millions)')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.show()
```

[image: Only Using Matplotlib]

**This is the plot with Matplot mixed with SymPy**

```
import sympy as sym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize'] = [10, 5]

t = sym.Symbol('t')

f = 6*t**3+5*t**2-3*t+16

t2 = np.arange(0, 100, 0.1)
f2 = [f.subs(t, x) for x in t2]

plt.plot(f2, t2, 'r')
plt.title('1-D motion through time')
plt.xlabel('Space (m)')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.show()
#a = sym.plot(f, (t,0,100), title = '1-D motion through time', xlabel = 'Time', ylabel = 'Space (m)', line_color = 'red' )
```

[image: Matplotlib & SymPy]

**Only using SymPy**

```
t, y = sym.symbols('t y')
f = y- 6*t**3 + 5*t**2 - 3*t + 16

sym.plot_implicit(sym.Eq(f ,100),(y ,0,6e6),(t,0,100), title = '1-D motion through time', xlabel = 'Space (m)', ylabel = 'Time', line_color = 'red')
```

[image: SymPy Only]

Comment: It should be possible to do this with SymPy's `plot_implicit` e.g. `plot_implicit(y - t**2, t, y)` vs `plot_implicit(y - t**2, y, t)`.

Comment: Appreciate it!  That helped a lot Oscar Benjamin, will upload the updated code later today.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to invert them with sympy, but you can end up using matplotlib to plot the way you need it. After you define your variable and the function, you can make a new array `t2` (I did it with spacing 0.1 between 0 and 100), and I made a list of values for the function, using `subs` to evaluating it accordingly. Then just make the plot using the horizontal axis your `f` and the vertical `t`.

```
import sympy as sym
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

t = sym.Symbol('t')

f = 6*t**3+5*t**2-3*t+16

t2 = np.arange(0, 100, 0.1)
f2 = [f.subs(t, x) for x in t2]

plt.plot(f2, t2, 'r')
plt.title('1-D motion through time')
plt.xlabel('Space (m)')
plt.ylabel('Time')
plt.show()
#a = sym.plot(f, (t,0,100), title = '1-D motion through time', xlabel = 'Time', ylabel = 'Space (m)', line_color = 'red' )
```

Output:

[image: output_plot]